# Linq compare between IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I have some issue comparing some IEnumerable to a Linq list.
I have

```
public class GlnRequest
{
    public IEnumerable<string> gln;
    public IEnumerable<string> varuNr;
}
```

And I have a table StackTable.

```
var saldo = (from n in _stockContext.tacks
                    where n.GLNkod == gln && n.Varunr == varunr
                    select n);
```

How do I pick the list from my GlnRequest?
I dont know where to start...
Please help

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  It's not clear what `tacks` is, what it contains, or what the `GLNkod` or `Varunr` members are... or what you're trying to do, for that matter.

Comment: It looks like you have a List<GlnRequest> so you need two 'select' in your linq query.  One which enumerates through the GlnRequest and the second to enumerate through the gln or varuNr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is hard to tell by your code what exactly you are trying to do but in order to access the 2 fields of GlnRequest you need a instance of the class first. You also should make a properties for the fields in the class.

```
 GlnRequest glnRequest = new GlnRequest(); 
 var saldo = (from n in _stockContext.tacks
                    where n.GLNkod == glnRequest.gln && n.Varunr == varunr
                    select n);
```

I am just showing how you have access to you fields. Of course this code will throw an exception because the IEnumerables are null at the moment, but according to your question you want to know hot to access you fields and that is the way.